# Js Date - Unix Time Stamp wrong result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unix-timestamp

Hi I have generated a Unix Time Stamp with an online generator and I choose that Date:

```
01/12/2020 @ 9:30pm (UTC)
```

Which gave me result: `1578864600`

I want to display it now in my react app: (date is my result above)

```
const timestamp = new Date().setMilliseconds(date);
  const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pl-PL', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    weekday: 'long',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
  }).format(timestamp);
```

But in my react app I am getting that wrong Date:

```
Tuesday, 14.01.2020, 17:07
```

Why it is calculating it wrong??

Comment: In which format you want the output to be in?

Comment: `1578864600` doesn't seem right at all, and `new Date().setMilliseconds(date);` is not the correct way to construct a date from a timestamp. Edit: ah, unix timestamp websites give seconds, not milliseconds? You are missing three zeroes: `new Date(1578864600000);` - results in `"niedziela, 12.01.2020, 22:30"` with the code you've given.

Comment: Unix timestamp is the number of seconds from 1. January 1970. You are creating a new Javascript DateTime object with the current date and than add several days with the setMilliseconds() function. To convert Unix timestamp to Javascript DateTime check this Stack Overflow answer: from unix timestamp to datetime

Comment: Please fix link

Comment: @ASDFGerte but I wanted 21:30 why It returns 22:30?

Comment: timezone probably? The timestamp you give above is in UTC. E.g. `new Date(1578864600000).toISOString();` yields `"2020-01-12T21:30:00.000Z"`, so yeah, it's a timezone issue.

Comment: It looks like `Intl.DateTimeFormat` has an option for timezone, and UTC must always be available, so just use that.

Comment: Yes, I have changed that to Europe/London and it shows the correct result, I have created new object new Date(date * 1000) and now works well

Comment: https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/examples/TimeZone.tsx